# Nginx + php5-fpm = 404 Error with alias location

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am an amateur front end web developer, and I recently bought a Ubuntu server to try to my hand at some backend development. I am trying to figure out how to serve a php file from an aliased location block using php5-fpm. I am getting a 404 - Page not found error. I have tried all of the proposed solutions I could find here with no luck. As I am still a beginner I would love a quick ELI5 as well and any pointers on the rest of my conf file, so I can learn something too. I should mention that the main root folder is running a flask app, and is the reason I am using an aliased location.

My virtual host:

Nginx conf file

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;

root /var/www/example;
large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
access_log /var/www/example/logs/access.log;
error_log /var/www/example/logs/error.log;


location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; #$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://app_test;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


 location /test_site {
     alias /var/www/test_site;
     index index.php index.html index.htm;
     location ~ .php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
     }
  }
```

php5 www.conf file

```
[www]
...
user = www-data
group = www-data


listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
#listen = /tmp/php5-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
...
```

My fastcgi_params file is default. I have checked both the php and nginx logs and there are no errors. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `alias` to work with nested locations using `fastcgi` is complicated.

Assuming that you have not over simplified your configuration, the `test_site` location does not need to use `alias`:

```
location /test_site {
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

This removes the `alias` directive, and solves the aliasing problem in the PHP block.

Note also: The regex on the `location ~ \.php$` block was wrong. The `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` directives are unnecessary.

The `nginx` directives are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).